# Para um melhor desempenho no banco PostgreSQL é melhor ter os produtos divididos em tabelas menores?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, postgresql, desempenho, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para administrar a venda de vários empreendimentos imobiliários. Neste sistema cada empreendimento tem um grupo de unidades disponíveis, tipo "Apto 21 - 2o Andar, Apto 34 - 3o Andar" etc.
   Preciso de desempenho para o corretor acessar uma unidade, ver a informações dela e até mudar a situação de venda dessa unidade. Ex: de disponível para vendido.
  Como a mesma construtora tem vários empreendimentos e atendo com o mesmo sistema várias construtoras; o sistema tem cadastrado na mesma tabela as unidades de muitos empreendimentos tendo um campo "empreendimento_id" como identificador do qual empreendimento ele faz parte para ser utilizado com filtro no espelho de vendas. Até aí tudo bem.
   Eu antes utilizava uma tabela "espelho_de_vendas" com todas as unidades, mas com o tempo a quantidade de empreendimentos foi crescendo, a tabela também e começou a ficar lento acessar e alterar informações de uma unidade. Então passei a utilizar uma tabela para cada empreendimento. Mas com isso dificulto consultas globais sobre desempenho de vendas no geral e um corretor vende mais de um empreendimento e com isso dificulta uma consulta geral de suas vendas já que elas estão distribuídas em várias tabelas. Não tenho problema em criar Querys para buscar as informações cruzando várias tabelas e reunir para a consulta. Mas gostaria de saber se estou correto em utilizar uma tabela por empreendimento, ou deveria ter deixado todos as unidades na mesma indexadas pelo id do empreendimento?

Comment: O ideal é representar sua necessidade em um MER para analisar, "ter os produtos divididos em tabelas menores" não faz muito sentido... você tem que manter a normalização dos dados... outro dado importante é o histórico dos registros, que hora podem ser vendidos, depois devolvidos, revendidos, etc... simplificando, poderia considerar como um controle de estoque normal e gerar a movimentação pelas vendas / compras / etc...

Comment: "mas com o tempo a quantidade de empreendimentos foi crescendo, a tabela também e começou a ficar lento acessar e alterar informações de uma unidade" isso é quantos registros? problemas de desempenho são resolvidas com índices, queries e configuração do servidor.

Comment: Olá Rovann, no caso de empreendimentos imobiliários ( loteamentos ou residenciais ), a quantidade de produtos é sempre a mesma e a venda de uma unidade não faz ela deixar de existir no estoque, pois não é um produto que é entregue ao comprador e por enquanto existir o financiamento a unidade continua de administração da construtora. A única diferença de uma unidade vendida para uma disponível é o campo "situacao" que passa de "Liberado" para "Vendido". E com isso é adicionado um registro na tabela de propostas com os dados de abertura do financiamento.

Comment: O unidade continua sendo mostrada no espelho de vendas independente da situação. Este é um tipo de produto que faz diferença tanto para o cliente quanto para o corretor ver a situação de todas unidades independente da situação. O movimento de venda não altera o tamanho da tabela, mas sim a adição de novos empreendimentos para venda. Se ele for um loteamento de 1.000 lotes, são 1000 novas unidades.

Comment: da mesma forma que um carro é único, e uma concessionaria tem um estoque de veículos, uma corretora / construtora também tem um estoque de imóveis (carros também são únicos [cada um tem seu chassis]).Atente-se também à questão do empreendimento que está financiado portanto ainda é propriedade da financeira (que pode ser a construtora), nesse caso o empreendimento sai do estoque dos 'disponíveis' e passa pro estoque dos 'financiados', eu pensaria em algo nesse caminho...  e a quantidade perguntada foi de registros no momento em que começou a ficar lento o sistema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso a identidade das tabelas é muito importante. Pois quando for fazer os relacionamentos com o index ira ajudar na performance.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que fica até melhor organizado. No meu ver, você deveria criar 4 tabelas: construtora, empreendimento, bloco e apartamento. A flag de vendido deve ser colocada para apartamento. Um join entre essas tabelas você conseguiria trazer a lista de apartamentos vendidos, com seu bloco, empreendimento e construtora. Mas claro, que para você criar o MER precisa ficar bem entendido a regra de negócio! Faça sempre a chave primária e estrangeira ser número e no caso seja usado N campos para filtro utilize índices! Num segundo momento, você pode pensar em tunning (mexendo nas variáveis de ambiente do postgresql.conf)

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo pra complementar a resposta?

Comment: Obrigado Carlos, pensei no custo benefício. Com os empreendimentos separados aumenta o tempo de resposta para o corretor consultar as informações de desempenho de vendas mas diminuí o tempo de acesso e edição da unidade na hora do processo de venda. Acho mais importante ter desempenho na hora da venda.

Comment: Fala meu caro Fabricio! Obrigado pela prestividade meu caro!